# Find server in JBoss Studio 8 through eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have installed through Marketplace the JBoss studio. `Eclipse Luna`

I try to set up using the instructions from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5ry5WpziVw) but in the 2:45 it mentions the server tab but I can see it. I have only Problems, Javadoc, Declaration. How can I see also the server tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse defines such things as 'views', and you can find them all in the menu under window -> show view. The servers tab is not a standard Eclipse tab so you will find it under 'other', but you may not find it there if you installed a basic Eclipse, you will probably need Eclipse for Java EE developers to have the required plugins installed by default.

But since you're working with JBoss, I assume that's the Eclipse package you installed anyway.